# Application gets restarted if the camera permission is changed

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I've implemented a short Flutter App which is requesting and checking the camera permission which works as expected. But, when manually changing the camera permission from the app settings, for both Android and iOS, it will restart my app. I need to mention that I've added in AndroidManifest.xml and Info.plist the required keys for camera. One interesting thing is that for the location the behaviour is fine and the app does not get restarted.

For permissions I'm using the permission_handler flutter library.

I don't know if is a flutter issue or a general mobile known behaviour but if someone knows more please let me know. If someone need some code example I can also provide this. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't get 'restarted', it gets killed. Meaning, it will run from app launch the next time. This is because some permission settings cannot be changed while the App is running. This is by design.

Comment: When I revoke a perm from settings, the app is killed by design but when I come back to the screen, I got a blank screen or a screen with my splash icon. How to manage to make the app restart when going back to it from the app manager ?

Comment: @Maxouille Simple, you don't. The system killed the App and only the user can reopen it. What is 'app manager'? If you see the 'launch screen' it means the App has started the lifecycle. If App was running before, the App was killed to get to this state.

Comment: Actually, when the app was running but killed by the system after revoking permission, it's still visible in the multitask (app manager for me sorry). From here, I can click on the app to reopen it but I only got a blank screen (make sense as the app is killed). Either I should not have the app in the multitask or it should restart properly I suppose

Comment: @Maxouille This is how iOS behaves. What you see in the multitask selector is only a pointer, it's not the actual App running. It's the same as pressing the App's icon.

Comment: I'm on Android btw but I understand. However, it should launch the app properly no ? I only got a blank screen. Just like the app was not loading data from my splashscreen.

Comment: @Maxouille Correct, it should launch the App 'properly'. You should be able to check that it's going the same path it goes through when App is first launched

Comment: Arf, it does not. I'm using flutter, may be that's part of the problem. Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

The native Android application's onCreate method is called after a permission is changed. Sometimes it may be called instantly after permission change and sometimes the OS may take upto several minutes to invoke application's onCreate.

Comment: unless you can cite public docs stating this behavior, your answer is nothing more than a guess.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34577479)